# Specifying storage.tsdb.retention in the config file rather than command line arg

Tags: prometheus

Is there a way to specify storage.tsdb.retention flag in the config file rather than pass on the command line?  I have different configuration files for different situations and it would be easier to manage if I can specify storage.tsdb.retention in the config file too.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to specify retention time except on the command line. Consider using [envdir](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools/envdir.html) to have a config on the file system that can inject a value for retention time (via an environment variable) from on-disk configuration.